# height:auto doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with `height` propery that doesn't work for me.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHWq9/).

I want the *white block* to be inside the *gray one* but it is not.

I hope you answer me what is wrong that white block is not inside the gray one.

CSS:

```css
#main-block {
    background:#eee;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888;
    -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888;
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #888;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.right-blocks {
    width:175px;
}
.right-blocks article {
    background: url(http://www.hotup.ir/upload/50n_b-top.png) no-repeat top;
    height:62px;
    width:175px;
    padding:9px;
}
.right-blocks article header {
    font-size:13px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:2px;
    color:#030434;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #0a3687;
    -webkit-text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #0a3687;
    -ms-text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #0a3687;
    -o-text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #0a3687;
    -moz-text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #0a3687;
}
.right-blocks article figure {
    font-size:14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:60px;
    color:#333;
}
.right-blocks article .b-main {
    background: url(http://www.hotup.ir/upload/crqy_b-main.png) repeat-y bottom;
    margin-top:-7px;
}
.right-blocks article footer {
    background: url(http://www.hotup.ir/upload/2623_b-bottom.png) no-repeat bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:5px;
    margin-top: -14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="main-block">
    <div class="right-blocks">
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <div class="b-main">
                <figure><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></figure>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <br /><br />
            </footer>
        </article>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help fixing?

Comment: why it doesnt work :| and I want the white block to be inside the gray one ...

Comment: Why what doesn't work?

Comment: Im bad in English ... sry guys :|

Comment: height:auto; doesnt work in #main-block id

Comment: @alireza As s side-note: you're using the HTML5 semantic tags in a wrong direction. `article` and `section` are not generic wrappers.

Comment: @alireza Update the question instead, and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take the `height: 62px;` out of the `.right-blocks article` css block.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d5HZJ/

Comment: @alireza : don't be sorry fella, question is what this community is for, just ask in proper format next time and `asap` is not something suggested...meanwhile, if it helped, mark this answer as accepted!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the height:62px from .right-blocks article. You can even remove:

```
.right-blocks {
width:175px;
}
```

it does nothing.